# How to model clustered data structure association when all clusters are observed at the same time?

Tags: lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, fixed-effects-model, hierarchical-clustering, clustered-standard-errors

I have data from many recipes I made that describes how different ingredients subgroups grouped in different parent categories (sweet, sour, bitter, umami ) work together to ultimately lead to scores given to each recipe along the parent categories dimensions.

Ultimately, I want to understand how adding more ingredients from one recipe category influences a score in *another* category.

Let me give a concrete example.

Here is how the data looks:

```
   overall_score | bitter_score | sweet_score |   
   sour_score | umami_score | 
   bitter_subgroup_1_ingredients | 
   bitter_subgroup_2_ingredients | 
   bitter_subgroup_3_ingredients | 
   sweet_subgroup_1_ingredients | 
   sweet_subgroup_2_ingredients | 
   sweet_subgroup_3_ingredients | 
   sour_subgroup_1_ingredients | etc..
```

For every row we have the number of ingredients added in each subgroup category and a

So The data is hierarchically clustered.
Cluster level 1: Parent category (sweet, sour, bitter, umami)
Cluster level 2: Subgroup of each parent category

We then have counts for how much was added from each subgroup.

What I want to know is _not) just how adding more or less from the subgroups of a category influences its score. Instead, I want to model how much adding more, say, bitter subgroup ingredients influences the overall score in umami.

I've been very confused in how to do this.

My first thought was: Let's start with fixed effects, with an effect for each subgroup, and add interactions between all the subgroups. I have many observation so this is feasible.

This of course ignores the first-level group effect (the parent category).

I know that when data is grouped by, say, school and classroom, we do the following:

```r
lmer(y ~ (1 | school) + (1 | school:class), 
    data = schools)
```

But this doesn't quite work for me because my data is wide, with one column for each subgroup and I'm ultimately interested in what happens when the subgroups are all inputs *together*, not when we model them one at a time as clusters.

This left me very confused. I'm not really sure how to specify my data. The best I've thought of is just to use dummy variables for all subgroups and categories and interaction terms between the categories to understand the associations. However, the within-group values are correlated. So I'm not sure this suffices.

I somehow need it to be:

```r
lmer(bitter_score ~ (1 + bitter_subgroup_1_ingredients + 
    bitter_subgroup_2_ingredients + 
    bitter_subgroup_3_ingredients | bitter_group) + 
    (1 + sour_subgroup_1_ingredients + 
    sour_subgroup_2_ingredients + 
    sour_subgroup_3_ingredients | sour_group) etc.., 
    data = recipes)
```

Where I fit a model for every category score. But this doesn't seem quite right.